# Calling Curl API on Python

Tags: python, api, curl

I want to call CURL API on python.

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization:Token 00d2e3a10c82420414b2d36d28fb5afc2cd8e8a5" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{"module_id":"[MODULE_ID]", "text": "example text"}' \
-D - \
https://api.tocall.com/
```

I used `requests` module for making request and `json` module for converting object to string. But I'm getting 404.

Where am I wrong?

```
import requests
import json
headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Token 00d2e3a10c82420414b2d36d28fb5afc2cd8e8a5',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}
url = "https://api.tocall.com/"
data = '{"module_id":"[MODULE_ID]", "text": "example text"}'
response= requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
print(response.status_code)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the `Host` header, so that the final server knows on which virtual host to route the request,

Change:

```
headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Token 00d2e3a10c82420414b2d36d28fb5afc2cd8e8a5',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}
```

For:

```
headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Token 00d2e3a10c82420414b2d36d28fb5afc2cd8e8a5',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Host' : 'api.tocall.com'
}
```

I think this will fix your issue. Eventually you might want to update the default headers, not craft your own ones. Try to use the [`session features`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/) of `requests` to perform consistent queries.

Note: as stated by other answers, you have other JSON encoding issues, but that's not the reason why you are getting `404`.

Answer (score 0):

You are encoding your data as JSON twice. `json.dumps()` takes an object and converts to JSON. In this case, you are converting a string to JSON. This should work better:

```
import requests
headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Token 00d2e3a10c82420414b2d36d28fb5afc2cd8e8a5',
}
url = "https://api.tocall.com/"
data = {"module_id":"[MODULE_ID]", "text": "example text"}
response= requests.post(url, json=data, headers=headers)
print(response.status_code)
```

If it still doesn't work and you need more help, you should include real details about your API so we can reproduce the issue.

Comment: This is certainly *a* problem to fix, but I'm not sure a bad payload would cause a 404 error.

Comment: I've seen APIs return 404 based on POST data. Maybe it's expecting some identifier there that's not found. With the amount of information provided and choosing to trust that the same URL was used in both cases, this is my best guess.

Answer (score 0):

`json.dumps` turns a Python `dict` to a string, but your `data` is already a string. The easiest thing to do is write `data` as a `dict` then use `json.dumps` on that.

Comment: Short and undetailed answers are most welcomed in comments.

Comment: It addresses the problem; why should I rewrite all of OP's code?

Comment: For answer's quality. You quote him, you show the fix. By reading you, noone needs to read OP. Or not.

Comment: I suppose. I just follow Stackoverflow's guideline for comments of "Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements. Avoid answering questions in comments." If my answer can be improved then all right, but I don't know why I should have posted a comment.

Comment: If you had followed them more, you would know that `Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better.` [How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) - I just encourage you to be on the right side, and will upvote you for any effort in this direction.